# "～とでもいうのか" meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I can not understand very well this "～とでもいうのか" found in Dragon Ball.

The context in this: Goku and Frieza begin to fight, and Goku say:

> "いいかげんにしろ。。。このクズやろう。。。罪もない者をつぎからつぎへと殺しやがって。。。クリリンまで。。。"

Frieza reply:

> "えらそうなことをいいやがって。。。きさまらサイヤ人は罪のないものを殺さなかったとでもいうのか?"

[image]

I found here on japanesestackexchange some topics in which has been discussed about this "～とでもいうのか". [Here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12202/can-anyone-explain-the-grammar-behind-the-sentence-ending-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82) is stated that is a expression for add emphasis. [Here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/what-does-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-mean) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21156/function-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-in-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B) it is says that "～とでもいうのか" stands for "or something".

So, which is the correct answer?
And, is this translation correct?

"You wouldn't be saying that you saiyan never killed innocent people?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can easily see in your [first answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12202/can-anyone-explain-the-grammar-behind-the-sentence-ending-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82), the sentence-end `～とでも(言うのか)?` is used almost as a set expression, and almost always has a fairly accusatory overtone; "Are you really saying ～?" I could not find a perfect explanation of this でも in monolingual dictionaries, so I think you can memorize this as a fixed pattern. But the closest definition in dictionaries was "～ or something like that", as your remaining answer says.

See also:

- [Meaning of "でも" in "食事でもどうですか？"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/5010)
- [Sentence ending with -とでも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12200/5010)

Answer (score 5):

I'll make my answer short, as it doesn't appear you are requesting too much explanation.

There are a few different interpretations of ～とでもいう that are very context dependent. The closest I found to this context would be a Weblio definition found [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86), namely:

> とでもいう　－　as if to say; as if; as though

I would translate it as:

> 'As if you damn Saiyans never killed any innocents!'

or

> 'Are you trying to tell me that you damn Saiyans never killed any innocent people!'

or something along those lines.